# how to link two fields in Brilliant Database

Tags: database

I need help in brilliant database 
anyone know anything about it ?
I need to know how I can link two forms together 
i.e the data in form 1 appear in fields of field 2 h

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use "brilliant database", but chose "My visual database" easier and free.